# Can you please move this from Webmasters SE to Information Security SE with bounty?

Tags: discussion

can you please move it to here with the bounty? I will gladly give it to any who will contribute such an explanation to the community of users which are not from the field of IS.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/100072/installing-comodo-rule-set-on-apache-based-modsecurity-module?noredirect=1#comment125574_100072

Comment: You would need to ask the mods of webmasters... I suggest you flag your question for moderator attention, and ask to move it. However, I think it might be better to move it to [sf] than to here...

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is No, we cannot do it - migration is a push, not a pull, so as @AviD commented, you'd need to ask the community there to migrate.

It really isn't on topic here though - everything you ask looks much more appropriate for Server Fault.